# Memory alignment of arrays

Tags: c, memory-alignment, dma

I am having trouble aligning memory for DMA transfer on the Cell processor. I need the last 4 bits of an address to be 0.

I have 4 arrays of `unsigned int` where each element must be *aligned* in memory so that its (hex) adress ends with a zero.

E.g.

```
int main()
{
    size_t i;

    static unsigned int a[2] __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
    static unsigned int b[2] __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
    static unsigned int c[2] __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
    static unsigned int d[2] __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));

    for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        printf("a[%u] = %p\n", &a[i]);
        printf("b[%u] = %p\n", &b[i]);
        printf("c[%u] = %p\n", &c[i]);
        printf("d[%u] = %p\n", &d[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a[0] = 0x10010b60
b[0] = 0x10010b50
c[0] = 0x10010b40
d[0] = 0x10010b30
a[1] = 0x10010b64
b[1] = 0x10010b54
c[1] = 0x10010b44
d[1] = 0x10010b34
```

The problem here is that the 2nd element of each array doesn't seem to be 16-bit aligned (their address' end with a 4).

I need the addresses to look like this:

```
a[0] = 0xXXXXXXX0
b[0] = 0xXXXXXXX0
c[0] = 0xXXXXXXX0
d[0] = 0xXXXXXXX0
a[1] = 0xXXXXXXX0
b[1] = 0xXXXXXXX0
c[1] = 0xXXXXXXX0
d[1] = 0xXXXXXXX0
```

Comment: `(aligned (16))` means align on 16-_byte_ boundaries.

Comment: The addresses you want to have are ending with 0. This means you need 16 byte alignment, not 16 bit alignment. Just a correction

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The alignment attribute specifies the alignment of *variables* or *structure fields*, not single array elements. See [Specifying Attributes of Variables](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html) and [Common Variable Attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html) for details.

If you always want to align two integers together, you can define a structure

```
struct dma_transfer {
    unsigned int e0 __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
    unsigned int e1 __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
};
```

This aligns the *elements* on 16 byte boundaries.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    static struct dma_transfer a;
    static unsigned int b[2];

    printf("a.e0 = %p\n", &a.e0);
    printf("a.e1 = %p\n", &a.e1);
    printf("b[0] = %p\n", &b[0]);
    printf("b[1] = %p\n", &b[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

gives, e.g.

```
a.e0 = 0x601060
a.e1 = 0x601070
b[0] = 0x601080
b[1] = 0x601084
```

But this means also, that you have holes between the two integer values. On a 32 bit system, you will have

> | int 4 bytes | hole 12 bytes |
> | int 4 bytes | hole 12 bytes |

Answer (score 6):

If `arr` is an array of 32-bit elements, and the address of `arr[0]` is `0xXXXXXXX0`, then the address of `arr[1]` will necessarily be `0xXXXXXXX4`.

For your purpose, you need to use arrays of 16-byte elements:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned char reserved[16-sizeof(unsigned int)];
}
element_t;

static element_t a[2] __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
static element_t b[2] __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
static element_t c[2] __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
static element_t d[2] __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
```

Alternatively, you can simply refrain from using arrays altogether.

Instead, use plain variables, and tell the compiler to align them to 16 bytes:

```
static unsigned int a0 __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
static unsigned int a1 __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
static unsigned int b0 __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
static unsigned int b1 __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
static unsigned int c0 __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
static unsigned int c1 __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
static unsigned int d0 __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
static unsigned int d1 __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
```

Answer (score 4):

I really don't think you can do that ... You're trying to get the compiler to inject extra padding for alignment purposes "inside" an `unsigned int`. But there's no space to do that, all of the bits in an `unsigned int` are already used for the integer itself.

I think the solution is to wrap the integer in a structure, since then you can use the `__attribute__(())` magic on the structure, and make an array of that.