# GCC __attribute__ ((aligned (8))) not working

Tags: c, gcc

I wrote about this problem in other posts. Although this is not the case.

> GCC compiler version: 4.8.3 (for ARM)

Code excerpt:

```
uint8_t data[4] __attribute__ ((aligned (8))) = {1,2,3,4};

int main()
{
    uint32_t p = 0;
    p = (uint32_t)&data[0];
    p = (uint32_t)&data[1];
    p = (uint32_t)&data[2];
    p = (uint32_t)&data[3];
}
```

Please note that **data** is outside any function, so it is **NOT** allocated in the stack.

The result I am seeing (when debugging) for `p` is: `536870912, 536870913, 536870914, 536870915;`

I am expecting something like this: `536870912, 536870920, 536870928, 536870936`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The individual elements of an array will be `sizeof(T)` apart, by definition.

Comment: @Mat yes this is what I do expect.

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth Then how can I allocate these elements in addresses multiple if 8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Memory alignment of arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367937/memory-alignment-of-arrays)

Comment: @Hairi - What is the actual use-case here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are telling the compiler to align *the array* on an 8-byte boundary. *Not* each of the members. Simple answer is - You cannot do it with a scalar datatype, as the compiler is not allowed to put any padding between array elements (after all, `*x++` as a pointer to uint8_t should still increment the pointer only by 1).

Something like

```
struct alignas(8) AL_BYTE{
   uint8_t theByte;
}
struct AL_BYTE data[4] __attribute__ ((aligned (8))) = {{.theByte=1},....
```

should achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I bet `aligned (..)` aligns an entire array instead of each item separately.

As far as I know the standard forbids any additional padding between array elements (size of array == size of each item * amount of items).

If you want each element to be aligned by 8-byte boundary, you need your elements to be 8 bytes large.

Possible solutions (combine them with `__attribute__ ((aligned (8)))`):

- An array of structs (`struct {uint64_t byte, padding[7];};`).
- An array of `uint64_t` (then you will need to make sure that you use only the lowest byte of each number). This will only work properly on lil-endian platforms.
- An array of `uint8_t`, 8 times larger than you actually need (again, you need to make sure that you use only bytes that you need).

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution is to `typedef` `char` with alignment into a new type, then make an array out of the new type, which unfortunately does not work in GCC, [demoed here](https://ideone.com/3wkueZ)

```
typedef char AlignedChar __attribute__ ((aligned (8)));

AlignedChar test[16]={};

//prog.c:4:1: error: alignment of array elements is greater than element size
```

Some details can be found among the comments in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36211864/how-can-i-apply-attribute-aligned32-to-an-int/36212200#comment60057995_36212200)

But this works for clang. clang's behavior is to change the `sizeof` the new type to include the alignment, which is desired.

I considered this a GCC bug and filed a bug report [70407](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70407).

Comment: I am really not sure whether I like the idea of allowing a `typedef` to change the alignment of a simple data type in an array. Note I am not saying it's right or wrong, I am not familiar with the standards enough. User-defined data types like structs, I'm generally fine with, but scalar data types like in your example - That gives me an itch.....

Comment: One of the itches is the meaning of `sizeof`as "size used" vs. "size valid" for scalars.

Comment: @tofro According to the standard `sizeof` is indeed "size used".